# How to install SSL client certificate from a webserver for both FF and IE?

Tags: javascript, .net, internet-explorer, firefox, ssl

After login, I want a web-page to be able to provide both firefox and MSIE-8+ web-site clients the ability to download and install a unique SSL client certificate for the website so they need never login again from that machine.

The back-end is simple and done - I have a directory on my linux web-server
where typing "make USER=$username ${username}.crt.pkcs12" will create a new
client key and a valid, signed  PKCS-12 SSL client certificate file .

But how to best provide a single method whereby both logged-in (with password)
MSIE and firefox users can download these certificates and bring up the
"install client certificate" browser GUI dialog ?

It is straightforward to simply push the certificate as a file of mime-type
 ? - say 'application/x-pkcs7-certreqresp' ?? 
so the user is prompted to save the file; but I want them to be prompted to
add the certificate for this website to the SSL certificate manager's client
cert store. 
[Then I found this for firefox](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Code_snippets/Miscellaneous#Adding_custom_certificates_to_a_XULRunner_application).

So this is fairly straightforward
but all I can find for [MSIE is this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.cryptography.x509certificates.aspx).

So it is simple to invoke firefox'x security manager API from javascript,
but I can find no way of doing so from MSIE's javascript - one would need
to invoke  .NET C# code to access the .NET APIs, and the X509Store APIs seem
not to be exported to MSIE javascript .

As I see it, options are then to provide a mono .NET web service on my linux
webserver and redirect requests from MSIE clients for the certificates to 
this service , which can then download .NET code that the client runs
to install the certificate ?

Or I can make MSIE clients download a "Install_Cert.VB" visual basic script
that will run "WinHttpCertCfg.exe" ?

Or is there some magic MSIE security manager javascript API that I'm just not finding ?

Sorry, I've been a windows refusnik since 1992; I use only Linux / Solaris / BSD / MacOS and do not have access to a windows machine.

Anyone been here before / have any advice to offer ?
If so, it would be much appreciated !
Thanks in advance,
Jason

Comment: I think you use the [Certificate Enrollment Control](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms867026.aspx) from VBScript.

Comment: Have you looked into what options you have for Chrome? I'm also interested in this.

Answer (score 1):

Probably not an answer you'd expect to get, but the easiest you can do is create an ActiveX that will put the certificate to the right certificate store in IE. Since ActiveX is only handled by IE, you will have IE-specific solution and you will need to have just one version of ActiveX control. For Firefox (and Chrome and Opera) you would need to find other solutions.

Comment: Many thanks Eugene! but please clarify: "the right certificate store in IE" and where I can find such documented - thanks!

Comment: Hmm ... I thought ASP .NET is the way to go. since it is fully supported by Apache mod_mono ? I could simply re-direct MSIE browsers to the mod_mono ASP .NET  page that would download the certficate and a C# .net ActiveX control to invoke the security manager interface ?  Or can I develop  C# to be compiled into a an ActiveX object by mono and then requested by MSIE clients ? Anyone know of any examples of this, especially then the name(s) of the MSIE X509Store objects I need to modify in order to bring up a "install certificate dialog", or where such might be documented ?

Comment: @JVD you don't need an ASP.NET on the server to serve ActiveX. Now, ActiveX controls are usually written in native languages (C++, Delphi). Writing them in .NET is both tricky and not quite handy in your case. If you use C++, you can call CryptoAPI functions of Windows. With Delphi you can use our SecureBlackbox components ( http://www.eldos.com/SecureBlackbox/ )

Comment: @EJP: yes, the site will be capable of generating keys ON BEHALF of logged-in clients - really, expecting the average computer user to know how to correctly generate a des key and x509 certificate is beyond the realms of plausibility - most have trouble entering their own email or address into  a web form !

Comment: @EJP (cont.): but every client will get their own UNIQUE password encrypted certificate to access the site - they'll have to enter a password  to decrypt their newly generated key when the browser installs it ; then this password is stored in their "keychain" (at least it is in firefox) and they are prompted to enter their keychain password once at browser startup.

Comment: @EJP (cont.): Then when they go to the site for the first time in a browser session , they are prompted once if they want to identify themselves with this certificate; they won't need to enter any password for the site if they click "yes" . So every client gets their own uniquely encrypted stream from the website. I don't see how this is "radically incsecure", and is IMHO at least more secure than using passwords and session cookies .

Comment: @EJP (cont.): ( ALL the above takes place entirely over HTTPS of course ). The encrypted, password protected PKCS12 files downloaded to clients contain X509 certificates signed by the site's single "trusted client CA cert".

Comment: @EJP (cont.):Of course, options will be provided to optionally use OpenID or a GNU PGP key, or to upload a public key, or just to continue using password and session cookies, but I think giving clients uniquely encrypted streams is the most secure option for a highly security sensitive site. I also have to be able to provide limited "access to all account info" for a single partner / affiliate account, and think being able to get affiliates to download and install a single certificate is a good solution to this problem.

Comment: I currently use manually generated SSL client certificates and apache's 'SSLFakeBasicAuth' option  to protect the administration area of the website with highly secure results; NO ONE except those who have installed a unique admin certificate can see anything under $site/admin/ - they get an SSL connection error. I'd like to make this the case for certain areas of the non-admin site too
to install an SSL client cert in explorer.

Comment: I am only lacking access to any documentation on the MSIE way of installing certificates via javascript, or of the ActiveX interfaces (preferably the object->classid) I need to use in order to bring up the "install SSL client certificate" GUI dialog on MSIE .

Comment: This is why I never bothered with windows - open-source software is so much better documented, and one is not reduced to trawling the web to discover anecdotes on how to use it .

Comment: @Eugene: RE: "ActiveX controls are usually written in native languages (C++, Delphi)." - precisely, but what to do if one has no access to a native windows compiler of any kind ? the only options are Mono or developing some kind of script - since JavaScript does not enable access to SecurityManager API, I guess that leaves only VBScript ? Can ActiveX controls be written in VBScript? Should the VBScript try to run "WinHttpCertCfg.exe" or is there some MSIE interface it should use to install an SSL client cert ?

Comment: <code>
public bool validateRemoteCertificate
 (object sender, System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509Certificate certificate, 
  System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509Chain chain,
  System.Net.Security.SslPolicyErrors sslPolicyErrors)
  {
 
            if (settings.IgnoreTgsCertificateError)
            {
                // allow any old dodgy certificate...
                return true;
            }
            else
            {
                return sslPolicyErrors == SslPolicyErrors.None;
            }
       }
</code>

Comment: to work around accessing an HTTPS server whose certificate expired.

Comment: My question is : how to access the "System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.*" API from a downloaded web-page ?

Comment: @JVD "what to do if one has no access to a native windows compiler of any kind ?" What kind of reason it is? It would be better if you updated your question (by editing it and adding "UPDATE" before the addition) with all the info posted in comments above. This would be more efficient.

Comment: @GregS : Aha! Thank You! Sorry I did not see your comment earlier ! Now at least I've got some dox to go by:  
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms867026.aspx
Indeed, this VBScript seems to be getting near what I need:
<pre>

Comment: Const AT_KEYEXCHANGE = 1
Const XECR_PKCS10_V2_0 = 1
Dim CertEnroll
Set CertEnroll = CreateObject( "CEnroll.CEnroll" )
CertEnroll.ProviderName = _
   "Microsoft Enhanced Cryptographic Provider v1.0"
CertEnroll.KeySpec = AT_KEYEXCHANGE
CertEnroll.GenKeyFlags = 1024 * (256*256)
CertEnroll.addCertTypeToRequest "ClientAuth"
CertEnroll.CreateFileRequest _
   XECR_PKCS10_V2_0, _
   "", _
   "", _
   "request.req"

Comment: @Eugene: "What kind of reason it is?" : well, since windows trashed one month of my work as a student in 1992 after I renamed a text file with a ".COM" extension, I started using Minix, then FreeBSD/NetBSD, then Linux + Solaris , and haven't looked back.

Comment: @Eugene (cont.): I have had to use it at work occasionally, but at the moment I have Solaris on the only possible windows disk partition and don't want to lose it. Yes, I must invest in an external hard drive and load windows-enterprise-server-beta (the only free version of windows) to eventually test this website extension , but at the moment I must work with resources available to me, which is Mono or Wine on Linux, (I can probably test VBscript with Wine) - and

Comment: @Eugene(cont.): I'd prefer not to make the website download executable machine code at all - I thought that was what HTML / JavaScript was meant to avoid, but I guess Bill doesn't agree.

Answer (score 1):

[Here's some documentation](http://www.w3.org/wiki/Foaf%2Bssl/Clients) about ways to get client side SSL certificates installed.

As you might expect, every browser is different, mobile devices are missing features in many cases, and there are lots of ways to do the same thing. Looks like many people are banging their heads on this stuff.

Answer (score 0):

What you are doing is radically insecure. Private keys are supposed to be private. So generating a private key for somebody else is a contradiction in terms. The corresponding certificate is also supposed to uniquely identify the client. In this case it could identify either the generating code or any of the client(s) to which it has issued the key and certificate.

You need another solution.

Comment: @EJP: yes, the site will be capable of generating keys ON BEHALF of logged-in clients - really, expecting the average computer user to know how to correctly generate a des key and x509 certificate is beyond the realms of plausibility - most have trouble entering their own email or address into  a web form - but every client will get their own UNIQUE password encrypted certificate to access the site - they'll have to enter a password  to decrypt their newly generated key when the browser installs it ; then this password is stored in their "keychain" (at least it is in firefox) and they are

Comment: <pre>
Const AT_KEYEXCHANGE = 1
Const XECR_PKCS10_V2_0 = 1
Dim CertEnroll
Set CertEnroll = CreateObject( "CEnroll.CEnroll" )
CertEnroll.ProviderName = _
   "Microsoft Enhanced Cryptographic Provider v1.0"
CertEnroll.KeySpec = AT_KEYEXCHANGE
CertEnroll.GenKeyFlags = 1024 * (256*256)
CertEnroll.addCertTypeToRequest "ClientAuth"
CertEnroll.CreateFileRequest _
   XECR_PKCS10_V2_0, _
   "", _
   "", _
   "request.req"
</pre>

Comment: Eventually, what I hope to achieve is:
o A custom apache 'mod_auth_XXX' module that triggers SSL client cert negotiation, if it fails, falls back to using cookies + password or users chosen external authenticator (eg. OpenID) , and  if this succeeds, presents users ability to download a unique password encrypted PKCS cert that they are prompted to install in MSIE or firefox browser GUI. (You almost don't need a custom module to do this, but it helps.)
I can't see any security problems with above if implemented correctly - can anyone else ?

Comment: @JVD: If you want to clarify your question, edit it. Don't put responses in edits to questions.

Comment: @nmichaels: then this website is broken, because it purports to allow  users to edit text they shouldn't - and the comment I made in my last post is lost. Why not fix the website instead of injecting unhelpful comments to this discussion ?

Comment: @JVD: You're clearly new here; I was trying to let you know how things are done. The reason your edit never showed up in EJP's answer is that it was rejected by people with edit privileges for the reason I gave in my previous comment. The reason for the edit button is so you can improve answers. Look at the "How to Edit" box that pops up when you click the edit button. See also the [faq](http://stackoverflow.com/faq)

Comment: @JVD None of that is relevant. What you propose remains insecure. If you want to make it easier for the user write an applet that executes at their end. Generating it at your end is not and cannot be secure and cannot possibly meet the objective for which the certificate is required in the first place. You lose non-repudiability for one thing. Ask your management whether that is really acceptable, because it is an inevitable consequence of the present design. This has very serious legal consequences so don't skimp on this enquiry.